# Create multipass VM with IP of local network

Tags: multipass

There seems to be significant amounts of info on configuring the network interfaces within multipass, but I am struggling to figure out what is likely quite easy?

My local network is 192.168.1.0/24 and VMs created within multipass end up with  10.179.232.113.  What is the preferred method for ensuring a machine on my local LAN where the multipass host resides, can directly access a VM once created?

Thank you in advanced.

Bob